# obtaining full file paths in git merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge, build-process

I'm working on a tool to analyse the output of merging many topic branches and produce a detailed conflict report. I've run into a slight problem in that sometimes Git will produce a truncated file name in the merge command's output, such as

```
Merge made by recursive.
 .../somepath/anotherpath/toolong/default.css     |    2 +-
```

When in other cases it gives the full path

```
Auto-merging thefullpath/to/myfile/default.jsp
```

I would like to always have the full path available in order to match files between merges.

Comment: `git diff --numstat branchA branchB` can be used for machine consumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your end goal, but I think I can provide an answer anyway.

If you want to get a good report of changes when a merge runs into conflicts, i.e. while everything is still uncommitted, you should use `git status --porcelain`. It gives a nice, machine-readable list of all files and their statuses (including merge conflict states) and is well-documented [in the manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html). Depending on your use case, you might even use `git merge --no-commit` to ensure you have the chance to inspect the merge result before proceeding (committing). You could also use `git diff HEAD --numstat` to get a machine-readable report of the added/removed line counts by file.

If you want to examine merges after the fact, it's a very good use case for [`git diff-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html):

```
git diff-tree -c --numstat <commit>
```

The `-c` tells it to diff merge commits against both parents, and the `--numstat` gets you a nice machine-readable output as before.

Finally, if you wanted to generate extremely detailed conflict reports, you could pass `-p` instead of `--numstat`, giving you full patch output. This is the kind of patch you'll see in `gitk`, where there are two characters at the start of each line, indicating whether the line was added/removed relative to each parent. Changes coming from just one parent have just one symbol (e.g. `'+ '`, `' -'`, quotes added to make spaces visible), while lines changed manually as part of conflict resolution will have two (`--`, `++`). You could parse it yourself if you really had to. (Unfortunately I don't think there's anything like `--numstat` on steroids for merge commits.)